# Blazor web assembly authentication: failing to authorize

Tags: authorization, blazor-webassembly

I wrote this basic Blazor web assembly application with authorization. I used `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[Authorize]` to allow/guard routes. But for some reason, I can't authorize myself to open a page. I am really struggling with this.

This is what gets rendered after redirects:

[image]

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

```xml
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity is { IsAuthenticated: true })
                    {
                        <text>You are not authorized to access this resource.</text>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <LoginRedirect/>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <text>Please wait, we are authorizing you ...</text>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

```cs
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        // ReSharper disable once InvertIf
        if (IsLoggedIn())
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _state.UserInfo!.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, _state.UserInfo!.Name)
            };
            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "auth");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)));
    }
```

[Repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/symmetric-crypto-chat-room/tree/dd16723430ae0912edc9f7ba7f4aa2b0110df2fb)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the authtication type to

> "Basic"

Claims identify [AuthenticationTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.authenticationtypes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1) needs to be a supported type

```
  identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
```

Then check to see if it's authenticated with

```
var isAuthenticated = identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: It didn't work.